# What method should I override to implement custom membership test?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have class, say A.
I made set of instances of A

```
s = set(A(1), A(2)...)
```

How do I test that instance is in s by using native 'in' operator, like

```
if A(3) in s:
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `dict`, you need to override `__hash__` and `__eq__`

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html for more details

> Accordingly, the requirements for set elements are the same as those for dictionary keys; namely, that the element defines both **eq**() and **hash**()